# Error Undefined variable: mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

No me lista mis datos en una tabla, no se si estoy fallando al llamar la consulta.

El error es:

> ```
> Error Undefined variable: mysqli_query
> ```

Código

```
<?php
    include ("db/conexion.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM infraccion";

$result =$conexionBD->query($query);

echo "hola";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="TablaMayor">   
        <center><img src="logo.png">
            <div id="titulo">
                <center><h1>Nombres, y valor de cada tipo de infraccion</h1></center>
            </div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="centro">
                        <td>id</td>
                        <td>Nombre Infraccion</td>
                        <td>fecha</td>
                        <td>valor</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php while ($row=$result->mysqli_query()) { ?>

                        <tr>    
                            <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo $row['nombre_infraccion'];?></td>
                            <td><?php  echo $row['fecha'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['valor'];?></td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JuanKGlezz   gracias por responder , pero lo que pasa es que no se en que lugar  se inserta el código

Comment: tu pega el código como texto, luego lo seleccionas y le das en `{ }` de la parte superior de donde estas escribiendo la pregunta

Comment: @Jhonny Para publicar el código, puedes utilizar 3 acentos graves para iniciar y 3 para terminar el bloque de código, o indentar el bloque a 4 espacios.

Comment: Creo que el error está en que tu código es demasiado breve

Comment: JuanKGlezz y NaCI gracias por su ayuda, este es mi codigo, pero no entiendo por que el error en la linea de la consulta,

Comment: En cuanto se reabra la pregunta te redacto una respuesta con la explicación del error y cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: Si mi respuesta solucionó tu problema recuerda marcarla como tal. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema en `$row = $result->mysqli_query()`.

Tu variable `$result` es una instancia de [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/mysqli-result), así que esa instrucción es errónea porque no existe el método (ni propiedad) llamado `mysqli_query()` en la clase `mysqli_result`.

En su lugar debes usar, por ejemplo, [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc) para obtener la siguiente fila de datos:

```
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
```

Además, como consejo, te recomiendo cambiar las líneas en las que das salida de datos al navegador:

```
<?php  echo $row['nombre_infraccion'];?>
```

Por la siguiente:

```
<?= htmlspecialchars($row['nombre_infraccion']) ?>
```

De ese modo evitarás cualquier problema de inyección HTML/CSS/JS o problemas de visualización de cadenas que contengan caracteres <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>, entidades HTML, etc.

Comment: OscarGarcia muchas gracias por tu orientación... bendiciones

Comment: seguire consultando, como darle solucion a lo que me dices de la salidas de datos al navegador

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que estás mezclando la interfaz de [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php#example-1818), es decir, la linea:

```
<?php while ($row=$result->mysqli_query()) { ?>
```

debería ser:

```
<?php while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
```

Comment: aldanux  muchas gracias por tu ayuda... bendiciones